# How do I mock Third parties in cucumber Stepdefs?

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, cucumber-jvm

I have a module that communicate with 3rd party service. 
In cucumber-jvm scenarios, how do you deal with mocking third party?

Comment: Please be more specific: are you trying to mock an external web service?  What type?  Are you looking for something like SoapUI?

Comment: we mock the third party, as you stated

Comment: Yes I'm trying to test an external Web service. I'd like to mock this web service in my stepdefs of cucubmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had similar problem and we used restito - [View GitHub](https://github.com/mkotsur/restito) and It works just fine, It is very robust tool. Restito will help you to mock Web Service. There will be no dependency on third party service.

Comment: Restito works perfectly fine with Cucumber :) Confirm. I am running test from last 1 month and all good.